# Access REST-API with Perl

Tags: rest-api

I want to access the REST-API from Perl (SOAP works) and found:
http://miguel.gualdron.com/2011/06/using-salesforcecoms-rest-api-from-perl.html

I tried this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib qw( /cw/CWPerlModules );
use feature say;

use CW::SalesForce::API;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $sf = CW::SalesForce::API->instance();
$sf->login();
my $sid = $sf{_}->{sf_sid};

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->add_header("Authorization" => "OAuth $sid");
$mech->add_header("X-PrettyPrint" => '1');
$mech->get("https://xy1.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/");
print $mech->content;
```

xy1.salesforce.com is address of our sandbox and also used for login with SalesForce::API.

Problem is that the login (with Mechanize) doesn't work:

Error GETing https://xy1.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/: Unauthorized at ./sf_test.pl line 17.

Error occurs when I try to get an url.

SF documentation says that I have to use OAuth 2.0 authentication for the REST-API.

Can someone point me in the right direction for using OAuth and the REST-API in Perl?